# Explicit homotopy of an entangled circle in a solid torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Original question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/why-is-this-entangled-circle-not-a-retract-of-the-solid-torus). It is problem 16(c), section 1.1 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

I'm trying to figure out an explicit homotopy that breaks the the entanglement. I suppose the first step would be to write down the path **A** explicitly. Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think such a homotopy exists?

Comment: @Paul...The projection of **A** to $S^1$ and $D^2$ are both null-homotopic and path connected, so the fundamental group $\pi_1(A)=0$, so there should exist a homotopy between **A** and a point in **A**.

Comment: Sure there is. And it's very easy to produce. But it "breaks the entanglement" by ignoring it and having no issue with passing the curve through itself.