# If $A$ is circle then why is $A $ contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Show that there are no retractions $r: X \rightarrow A$ in the following cases:

(c) $X = S^1 \times D^2$ and $A$ the circle shown in the figure.

[image: entangled circled from Hatcher, p.39]

My attempt : I found the answer  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/why-is-this-entangled-circle-not-a-retract-of-the-solid-torus)  But i didn't undertstand  the answer.If $A$ is circle  then  why is $A $  contractible ?

**My thinking**:  I had two things in my mind.

**case I**: Here $\pi_1(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} \implies $
Every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic $\implies$  the homomorphism $i_* : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is  injective

**Cases II** :let $i : A \hookrightarrow X$  be the inclusion , and fix  $x_0 \in A$.The induced map $i_*:\pi_1(A,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$  is defined by $i_*([f])=[if]$

we know that $[f] \in \pi_1(A,x_0)$ where $f: S^1 \to A$ is a loop based  at $x_0$

similarly $[if] \in \pi_1(X,x_0) $ where $if: S^1 \to X$  is a loop based  at $x_0$

**Use  the fact : circle is not contractible**

Also, it is given that $A$ is  circle $\implies \pi_1(A,x_0) \cong \mathbb{Z}$  which  is non-trivial

similarly $\pi_1(S^1 \times D^2) \simeq \pi_1(S^1) \times \pi_1(D^2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ which is non-trivial

This implies the inclusion $i: A \hookrightarrow X$  induces a non-trivial map $i_* : \pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(X)$

Therefore  $i_*$ is injective

**Tell me where I'm wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $A$ is a circle then why is $A$ contractible?

The space $A$ is circle. So, as a topological space, $A$ is *not* contractible. On the other hand, $A$ is embedded in $X$.  Let $i_A : A \to X$ be the inclusion map.  The answer you found shows that $A$ is contractible as a *subspace* of $X$.  That is, there is a homotopy $H : A \times I \to X$ that begins at $i_A$ and ends at a constant map. Thus $(i_A)_* : \pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(X)$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is *not* contractible as a topological space. However, any loop in $A$ is contractible *as a loop in $X$*.

This means that the injection $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ induces the null morphism between the fundamental groups : $$0=\pi_1(i):\pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(X) \tag{1}$$